# Can't trigger action on click - react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm creating my app with *react-native* and also using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md) for routing.
I have this piece of code in my `router.js` file and trying to add a button on the right that once is clicked it should trigger `sayHello` action.

```
const CoinImg = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image style={{width:20, height:20}} source={require('./myyImage.png')}/>
    </View>
  );
};

<Scene
          onRight={() => Actions.sayHello()}
          renderRightButton={() => { return <CoinImg />; }} 
          key="firstComponent"  
          component={FirstComponent} 
          title=" " 
        />
```

The above code can correctly show image on the right but when I click that image nothing happens (action sayHello() is not triggered).
Instead, If I have the following code the action is triggered.

```
<Scene 
          onRight={() => Actions.sayHello()}
          rightTitle="Print Hello"
          key="SecondComponent"
          component={SecondComponent}
          renderTitle={() => { return <CoinImg />; }} 
        />
```

dependencies versions:

```
"react": "15.3.2",
"react-native": "0.34.1",
"react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0"
```

Comment: show me your sayHello() function

Comment: react native version?